# Trouble with a "Missing argument 1 for ProjectsController::show()"

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working with a projects controller and I keep getting this error message:

```
Missing argument 1 for ProjectsController::show()
```

I do not understand what could be wrong because it looks like my code matches the book and my other working controllers.  It was working fine until I added the Repository.

Below is the controller code:

```
use Web\Records\ProjectRecord;
use Web\Forms\ProjectForm;
use Web\Repositories\ProjectRepository;
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

protected $projectForm;
protected $projectRepository;


public function __construct(ProjectForm $projectForm, ProjectRepository $projectRepository)
{
    $this->ProjectForm = $projectForm;
    $this->ProjectRepository = $projectRepository;
}


/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /project
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return View::make('projects.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 * POST /projects
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::all() ;
    $this->projectForm->validate($data);

    $project = new Project;
    $project->name = $data['name'];
    $project->save();

    return 'project created';
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 * GET /project_creation
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($project_id) <- This is where it says the error is
{
    return View::make('projects.show')->with([
        'project' => $this->projectRepository->findBy($project_id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Even though it is in the routes file

Comment: Here is the routes: Route::get('/project', 'ProjectsController@index');
    Route::post('/project_creation', 'ProjectsController@show');

Comment: Route to the update method....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route to the update method should look similar to this, you are probably missing the `/{id}` argument there

```
Route::get('/project/{id}', 'ProjectsController@show');
```

Similarly *some* other routes should have the parameter, lets say update

```
Route::put('/project/{id}', 'ProjectsController@update');
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified that @show should receive $project_id when it's hit so make sure your routes file passes it.

You do that with

```
Route::get('/project/{id}, 'ProjectsController@show');
```

Comment: How is your answer different from mine?

Comment: When I began answering him your answer wasn't submitted and when it was submitted it only referenced put and update so I attempted to respond with his routes / goal in mind, likely just as you updated your answer to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are wrong from your comment you have

```
Route::get('/project', 'ProjectsController@index');
Route::post('/project_creation', 'ProjectsController@show');
```

This means that /project calls your index method in which you currently call your `create.view` this should return a view listing all of your projects.

And posting to /project_creation calls your show method which correctly returns a single project but you shouldn't be posting to this route.

I'm guessing you're trying to create a resourceful controller in which case you only need one route

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

And now your controller should have the following methods

```
public function index()
{
    //return a view that lists all projects
}

public function create()
{
    //return a view that contains the form for creating a new project
    //and posts to /projects/store
}

public function store()
{
    //Accepts the form and creates the project
    //returns the user to where ever they need to go
}


public function show($id)
{
    //expects the url to be /projects/project_id
    //returns a view showing the specified project
}
```

You may need other functions in your controller such as edit, update and destroy but I couldn't tell from your snippet. If these aren't needed change the route to

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController',
                [except => ['edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised why you're extending Controller instead of BaseController, or what version are you using?